# `company` completion with following text

Tags: company-mode, completion

When there is text immediately following point, `company` completion does not activate.

E.g. where `|` is point and `[...]` are completions:

```
;; Completion
foo.|
    [bar]
    [baz]
    [quux]

;; No completion
foo.|irrelevant-text
```

Is there a way to make completion *always* activate, even when there is text immediately following point?

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: Would this be easy/hard to add?

Comment: Moderately. Here's the issue to follow: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/340